# Is Kube-master should be able to contact slaves?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubletes(slaves) have to be able to query the kube-master-api. 
But it's not clear for me if the master node will then push/communicate with its slave.

In short: is a cluster with an external master node that can't reach slaves adresses would work?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The master has to be able to reach the nodes for API calls like pods/proxy, pods/log, pods/exec, etc to work.